# Detecting fetch TypeErrors in promise chain

Tags: javascript

Currently, I'm using fetch with redux-thunk to read code from an API -

my code reads like this:

```
export function getUsers() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    // I have some helper code that automatically resolves the json promise
    return fetch(`/users`)
    .then((resp, json) => {
      if (resp.status === 200) {
        dispatch(getUsersSuccess(json));
      } else {
        dispatch(getUsersFail(json));
      }
    }).catch((err) => {
      // network error
      dispatch(getUsersFail(err));
    });
  };
}
```

The problem here is the `catch` method, as it will `catch` any error thrown in the `then` block. This commonly means that if some React component's render function fails with a programmer error, that error gets swallowed up back into `dispatch(getUsersFail(err))`.

Ideally, I'd like to detect if `err` is a fetch error (and dispatch my own action), otherwise throw. However, fetch throws a generic `TypeError`. How can I reliably detect that the error caught was one thrown by fetch?

Comment: What promise implementation are you using that will pass two arguments to a `then` callback?

Comment: my "fetch" function is actually a wrapper around window.fetch - `f(u, opts).then(res => Promise.all([res, isJson(res) ? res.json() : {}]))`. It doesn't actually pass 2 arguments, but 1 argument that is an array, that I use the spread operator to expand `([resp, json]) =>`

Comment: Ah, thought so. Btw, you might want to consider adding `if (!res.ok) return res.json().then(json => { throw json })` to your wrapper so that you don't need to detect the status code in your `getUsers` function, and could just write `fetch('/users').then(getUsersSuccess, getUsersFail).then(dispatch)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `.catch()` but install the error handler directly on the fetch promise, as the second - onreject - argument to `.then()`:

```
return fetch(`/users`)
.then(([resp, json]) => {
  if (resp.status === 200) {
    dispatch(getUsersSuccess(json));
  } else {
    dispatch(getUsersFail(json));
  }
}, (err) => {
  // network error
  dispatch(getUsersFail(err));
});
```

Check out the [difference between `.then(…).catch(…)` and `.then(…, …)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572) for details.

Btw, I'd recommend to write

```
return fetch(`/users`)
.then(([resp, json]) => resp.status === 200 ? getUsersSuccess(json) : getUsersFail(json)
     , getUsersFail)
.then(dispatch);
```

Comment: I *want* to catch the errors thrown by Fetch however. For example, if our API is down, or if the user's internet is spotty I want to communicate that error to the user. However, what I've found is that the call to ` dispatch(getUsersSuccess(json))` can throw for whatever reason (for example if a React component throws an error in a different part of the code, and the render method was in this chain) - I still want to able to throw those errors.

Comment: @killachaos That's exactly what the code in my answer does.

Comment: My mistake,  I didn't actually test your code. Your link mentions this is an anti-pattern though however I'm not sure if I should ignore this - as I really want to avoid catching errors not related to that block of code.

Comment: @killachaos The *answer* to the linked question explains why (when) it is *not* an antipattern :-)

Comment: what do you think about specifying the catch first? i.e. `fetch(u).catch(err => networkFail(err)).then(getUsersSuccess)` it looks awkward but is more readable than `then(s,f)` for callbacks where we need to do some preprocessing before we dispatch. My only concern is it doesn't look idiomatic and it isn't immediately clear why the order matters here.

Comment: Actually that doesn't fully work, as the then() will still get resolved.

Comment: Yes, to always get either of the two callbacks executed and never both, you have to pass them to the same `then` call. (The only exception to that rule is when the rejection callback *always* throws, in that case you could do both `.then(x, thrower)` and `.catch(thrower).then(x)`)