# axios then and catch executed both executed on IE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, axios

I am making an axios `GET` request on IE and both the code within the `then` and `catch` callbacks are both being executed. Firstly it is successful, and then it runs into the error block.

This is only happening on Internet Explorer. Works fine on Chrome, safari and firefox.

Can anyone spot a silly error I may be making.

```
export const getData = () => {

    return dispatch => {

        dispatch(getDataRequest());

        // This appears once in the console
        console.log('CALLED');

        axios.get(`${cmsPath}/casinocms.cache.json`).then(res => {

            // Firstly I see this in the console
            console.log('NO ERROR!');

            dispatch(getDataSuccess(res.data));

        }).catch(err => {

            // I then also see this message in the console, 
            // following the message above

            console.log('ERROR!')
            dispatch(getDataError(err));

        });

    };
};
```

Comment: It would mean that `dispatch(getDataSuccess(res.data));` throws an exception. Don't you see what  `err` is?

Comment: Have a look at the [difference between `.then(…, …)` and `.then(…).catch(…)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572)

Comment: What is `Promise.reject(err)` doing there? That only causes an unhandled rejection.

Comment: @Bergi I put that in as an attempt to get this to work. Have removed again. The `getDataSuccess` is just an action that is sent to the reducer. Not sure how this would throw an error. And as i said this is just on IE

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting errors in promise chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42381446/detecting-fetch-typeerrors-in-promise-chain)?

Comment: I don't know how or why this would throw an error either. What debugging have you done? What *is* the error?

Comment: @Bergi I have been debugging for the last 5 hours. Have tried everything. Have only just realised that it was calling both then and catch blocks.

Comment: No other results in 5 hours of debugging? Have you at least done `console.log(err)`?

Comment: @Bergi this was the question from earlier that no one could answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45978423/issue-with-axios-unhandled-promise-internet-explorer?noredirect=1#comment78916690_45978423